# How to disable WhatsApp group message notifications?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

I'd like to only receive notifications (in the notification-bar) from single contacts but I don't know how to disable them without disabling all notifications from Whatsapp (via Settings->Apps).

Does anyone have a clue how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to mute group messages is to mute them for a time period, and the maximum duration is 1 week. To do this, open the group conversation you'd like to mute, press `menu` and select `Mute` and then select the desired duration (8 hours, 1 day, 1 week).

Unfortunately this means you have to do this weekly and separately for all groups.

Comment: Looks like they have added a n option to mute for 1 year.

Comment: moreover, it is possible to disable notifications. very useful.

Answer (score -1):

You could load a silent .mp3 sample as well.

Comment: This does not prevent the notification from showing up in the notification bar as Hedge is looking for.